# GitHub API can`t add maintainers while creating a team

Tags: github-api

I am trying to create a team in GitHub organisation using GitHub API. The problem is that I can`t add maintainers to the team.
The officiaal documentation says:

```
maintainers array of strings
List GitHub IDs for organization members who will become team maintainers.
```

I am using Python and here is how I pass maintainers in request body: ['43115086']
However, I get this Response, which doesn`t create a team for me.

```
{'message': 'Validation Failed', 'errors': [{'resource': 'Team', 'code': 'unprocessable', 'field': 'd
ata', 'message': 'Invalid maintainers were specified.'}], 'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.c
om/rest/reference/teams#create-a-team'}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn`t find any information on this error in the oficial documentation. Maybe somebody has already faced this problem? Or maybe you have any suggestions on how to solve it?
I would be very grateful for any advice!

Here is the function, from which I send the request:

```
def create_team(self, name, maintainers):
    url = self.ORGANIZATION_URL + "/teams"
    body = {
        "name": name,
        "maintainers": maintainers
    }
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {os.environ.get('GITHUB_TOKEN')}"
    }
    requests.post(url, json=body, headers=headers)
```

Token is not expired and the url is correct as well. This request works if I remove "maintainers" from request body.

Comment: The error may actually be in other parts of your request. Please provide minimal complete example that fails for you, including any boilerplate request-making code and how exactly the request is formed. *Do not* provide the access token. Even better, provide _full_ HTTP request exactly as sent to GitHub, but *without* the access token, as well as _full_ HTTP response from GitHub.

Comment: @yeputons added request to question

Comment: Are users you're trying to add as maintainers already organization members?

Comment: @yeputons yes and they have public organization visibility as well